# cast string to array php

Tags: php, arrays

I have a PHP array, but when I `var_dump($array)` it returns it as a string.

```
$array = file_get_contents("http://url.com");

array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(1874) "array(
  'response'=>array(...
```

I tried to do `var_dump( (array) $array)`, but that returns the same array as a string again, except this string is now in a single array value.

Any idea on how I can turn this "array" into an actual array?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide the code that sets up the contents of the $array variable?

Comment: I'm doing a file_get_contents of a function that returns a response of `array(
  'response'=>array('numFound'=>284075,'start'=>0,'docs'=>array(` etc..

Comment: Sorry I misinterpreted your comment.

Comment: Maybe eval is a better solution. mixed eval ( string $code ), although it comes with risks.

Comment: $file_str = file_get_contents("http://url.com"); $file_arr = explode("\n", $file_str); are you trying to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`file_get_contents` returns a string. it is not an array. better option would be to have your function returns a `json` string and do a `json_decode` on it from the client side

Answer (score 1):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php#93529

or you can resort to the evil eval?